# Combining two interpolating functions in terraform to assign access_keys to a list of users

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I have recently started using aws+terrafom. 
I have list of users that I want to create in a loop and assign access_keys to them. 
I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong method or approach to solve it.

I adapted the module aws_iam_user to create the list of users with count and it works fine. It's just when I'm trying to creates keys for each user that only the first user get credentials.

```
variable "name" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["neo", "trinity", "morpheous"]
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "this" {
  count = "${length(var.name)}"
  name = "${element(var.name,count.index )}"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "this" {
  count = "${length(var.name)}"
  user = "${element(aws_iam_user.this.*.name,count.index)}"
}
```

I was expecting each user to get access_keys but it only assigns them to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in which version of Terraform you are, but you should not need to add the wildcard

```
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "this" {
  count = "${length(var.name)}"
  user = aws_iam_user.this[count.index].name
}
```

Comment: Glad that it help :)